# neo4j does not return node by person name

Tags: c#, asp.net, neo4j, graph-databases

Here's the [Text View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uHlJ.jpg)

I am working on neo4j with Family Tree. When I ask to return a node with a specific name it does not work with any node except fro the root node. See the examples:

```
MATCH (n:FamilyTree {name: 'Sam'}) RETURN n
```

Sam is the root node and the neo4j returns that node.

But when I try to return some other node like this one:

```
MATCH (n:FamilyTree {name: 'Sumiko Shackleford'}) RETURN n
```

It does not return any thing. This node does exist in my Graph.
Could anyone help me?

This is the import statement:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///FamilyTree.csv" AS row 

    CREATE (:FamilyTree { ssn: row.SSN, name: row.Name, gender: row.Gender,
     status: row.Status, age: row.Age})
```

I imported the same data into SQL server and I got some weird character like 'Ê'
Is there any direct way to remove such a thing from neo4j?

I removed it from SQL server sing this query:

```
UPDATE familyTreeTest.dbo.FamilyTree
SET Name = REPLACE(Name,'Ê', '')
```

Comment: You're going to need to provide more information about the node you think should be returned. What is its label, and can you inspect its name property? There's a chance it's either of a different label, or maybe the name property key or value has spaces present preventing the match.

Comment: The label I am using is name as shown in the Cypher Query. I checked its spelling and everything is fine. The key has space in the middle 'Sumiko Shackleford' as you can see here but I think this is not the problem. I changed the root node name form 'Sam' to 'Test test' and it returns it with no problems.

Comment: If you can create a query that returns your 'Sumiko Shackleford' node, and copy and paste the Text result view of the node, maybe this can show something that we aren't able to see in the Row or Graph results views. Separately, also a good sanity check to see if this can return anything: `MATCH (n:FamilyTree) WHERE n.name STARTS WITH 'Sumiko' RETURN n`

Comment: gender F


name Sumiko Shackleford  


age 4


status Alive


ssn 101-100-297

here is the Row view. I am so sorry I am not familiar with stackoverflow yet. I try to upload an image as a comment but I do not know how to do that. pleas try to copy the result some where else and see it. I have four labels: gender, name, age, status, and ssn.

Comment: You can't add images in comments, please edit your description above and add it there.

Comment: gender F name Sumiko Shackleford age 4 status Alive ssn 101-100-297

Comment: Again, please edit your question (there should be an edit link you can click), and paste in the image of the Text view of the results (a view of the Graph view of the results would be a good addition too, if you can highlight the node in question so we can see its properties and labels). The screenshot may capture something that is hard to see or is cleaned up when pasted as just text.

Comment: Thanks for the image, that's the Rows view. From the views available to the left of the results, can you click on Text, and then add the image for the text view to your question?

Comment: you can see the text view up there now. so sorry for the inconvenient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is clear when you look at the text results image you added. If you look at the name, it has trailing spaces, so your matches fail because the spaces aren't present.

You're going to need to clean up your data so this won't happen with this or other nodes. You can clean it up like this:

```
MATCH (n:FamilyTree)
SET n.name = trim(n.name)
```

EDIT

Looks like whatever characters are present, they're not spaces, tabs, or newlines, but some other character that renders as whitespace.

The fastest way to clean this up is to find a way to clean up your input CSV files, and then reimport all your data.

Comment: I did that and still having the same issue.

Comment: Can you add in two new screenshot of the text results for Sumiko's node? One for the query that isn't working, and one for a query that is working (the STARTS WITH query)?

Comment: You can see it now attached to your answer.

Comment: I rejected the edit, please add it to your own question or link it from a comment, it doesn't make sense to add your own image link to my answer.

Comment: The image you did try to add still had trailing spaces. As far as I can tell, you didn't run the query to fix this. We can perform a check to see if it's not doing what it's supposed to. Try running this: `MATCH (n:FamilyTree) WHERE n.name STARTS WITH 'Sumiko' RETURN TRIM(n.name)` and attaching the screenshot of the text results.

Comment: please see the image above. It has the last query result.

Comment: BTW, I ran the trimming query more than one time.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot. Something odd is happening, TRIM() isn't working, so these aren't spaces, but some other characters that are rendering as whitespace. How did you import your name data into Neo4j? There's a good chance whatever input source you're using is using some non-standard characters somewhere. As far as options to clean it up, it may help to see if all of your nodes have trailing whitespace-like characters, and if so, if it's the same number of characters for all of them. If so, we can force a truncation of the name property for all nodes.

Comment: Otherwise, it may be a good idea for you to install [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures) (use the correct APOC version for your Neo4j version. APOC has a means of cleaning textual data, but it also has a side effect of transforming the string to lower case too, so you'll have to figure out a workaround somehow.

Comment: The problem was because the names on csv file had two spaces at the end. I fixed it and it worked just fine. thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: That's still odd, the TRIM() function should get rid of any spaces. Maybe they were in some other format?

Comment: No it was in CSV format but as I mentioned earlier when I import the same data into SQL Server I got some weird characters. I think TRIM() did not work because there was something it was not an empty space towards the end.